# What does the expression "print(1) and print("0") return in python?

Tags: python, printing, conditional-statements

I am learning Python 3. As far as I know, the print() function in Python 3 return `None`. I could find one website [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/print) that says the same thing.
In that case, when we apply the "and" operator between two `print()` functions, it should print `None` because `None and None = None`. I tried this with various print functions and the results seem to have been very different from what I was expecting. Here are the results. I tested them in Microsoft Visual studio 2015

`print(0) and print(0)` prints `0`.
 `print(0) and print(1)` prints `0`.
 `print(1) and print(0)` prints `1`.
 `print(1) and print(1)` prints `1`.

I tried this with the "or" operator and the results even more surprised me.
`None or None` should return `None`. Here are the results.

`print(0) or print(0)` prints `0 0`.
 `print(0) or print(1)` prints `0 1`.
 `print(1) or print(0)` prints `1 0`.
 `print(1) or print(1)` prints `1 1`.

What is the reason behind such behaviour ? Shouldn't the "or" operator return just one value? Please help me out here.

Comment: Your expressions *are returning `None`*, but they are *also* printing the arguments to the first `print` call and both `print` calls (in the case of `or`) due to the way the boolean operators short-cicuit

Comment: `None and any-object` is `None`, since `any-object` is ignored.  It is normal for programming languages to evaluate from left-to-right, with `and` it keeps going until something is "falsey" (like `None`), with `or` it keeps going until something is "truthy".

Comment: @cdarke: Unless Visual Basic.NET. I still have nightmares, even fifteen years later. (I think `AndAlso` and `OrElse` weren't yet introduced then)

Comment: @Amadan: I said *normal* :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logical operator performs [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

That means for `and`, the right-hand side os only evaluated if the left-hand side is "true". And for `or` the right-hand side is *not* evaluated if the left-hand side is "true".

In Python the value `None` is not "true", the right-hand side of the `and` statements will not execute.

Similarly for the `or`, since the left-hand side is not "true" the right-hand side will execute.

As for the output you get, it's the output of the `print` function calls. With the `and` you get the output from only the left-hand side `print` calls, with `or` you get the output from both calls.

Answer (score 4):

"Returning" and "printing" are different things. `print` will always return `None` and print whatever you give it, if called. The thing that surprises you is the behaviour of Boolean operators, not `print`.

`x or y` is defined as "The value of `x` if truthy; else, the value of `y`".

`x and y` is defined as "The value of `x` if falsy; else, the value of `y`".

Crucially, `y` is not evaluated if `x` fits the operator's criterion. This is called short-circuiting, and is pretty unique to `and` and `or` operators.

Now, `None` is a falsy value; thus `None and y` will never evaluate `y`, while `None or y` will always evaluate `y`. This is the reason why your `print(...) and print(...)` prints one value (the second `print` isn't executed because of short-circuiting), and why `print(...) and print(...)` prints two (both need to be evaluated to determine the result of `and`, as no short-circuiting is possible).